# How can I remove a part of an axis?

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization

I am trying to draw a graph whose x-axis begins after the y-axis. As you can see, the x-axis crosses the y-axis and continues to the left.

```
a = 2; U[x_] := -(a/x)^6 + (a/x)^12; min =     
 Solve[D[U[x], x] == 0, x]; xmin = min[[2, 1]][[2]]; potmin = 
 Solve[U[xmin] == Um, Um]; Umin = potmin[[1, 1]][[2]]; k = 
 D[U[x], {x, 2}] /. x -> xmin; 

Show[Plot[U[x], {x, 1.9, 3.8}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["r", FontSize -> 20, Black], 
Style["U(r)", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, 
PlotRange -> {{1.5, 4}, {1.5 Umin, 0.6}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Energia potencial"}, {Right, Top}], 
   Ticks -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {1.8, 0}], 
  Plot[Umin + k/2 (x - xmin)^2, {x, a, xmin + xmin - a}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Aproximação harmônica"}, {Right, Top}]], 
  Plot[Umin, {x, 1.8, xmin}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}], 
  Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
  Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
  Graphics[Text[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\)]\)", FontSize -> 20], {xmin,
      0.06}]], 
  Graphics[Text[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(min\)]\)", 
     FontSize -> 20], {1.651, Umin}]], 
  AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]}]

enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: Well, did you draw the above using Mathematica? Look at `PlotRange`. May be this will do it. But hard to try if you do not post code used.

Comment: If I change the plotRange the U_min will disappear

Comment: Only the change the x-axis in the PlotRange command. Leave the y range as `Automatic`?

Comment: The problem is when I use plotRange in x, it'll cut the leftside of the image

Comment: Could you please include the code required to produce the plot? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Ok, I edit the question.

Comment: @AndreLuizMB many thanks :) I tried something, so you can have a look

Comment: Is "`enter code here`" intended to be part of the code?

Comment: No, my mistake. sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

---

### **Edit 2: Placing the $U_{min}$ out of [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)**

---

The code is:

```
a = 2; U[x_] := -(a/x)^6 + (a/x)^12; min = 
 Solve[D[U[x], x] == 0, x]; xmin = min[[2, 1]][[2]]; potmin = 
 Solve[U[xmin] == Um, Um]; Umin = potmin[[1, 1]][[2]]; k = 
 D[U[x], {x, 2}] /. x -> xmin;
p1 = Plot[U[x], {x, 1.9, 3.8}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["r", FontSize -> 20, Black], 
     Style["U(r)", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{1.8, 4}, {1.5 Umin, 0.6}}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Energia potencial"}, {Right, Top}], 
   Ticks -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {1.8, 0}];
p2 = Plot[Umin + k/2 (x - xmin)^2, {x, a, xmin + xmin - a}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Aproximação harmônica"}, {Right, Top}]];
p3 = Plot[Umin, {x, 1.8, xmin}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
Show[p1, p2, p3, Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
 Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
 Graphics[Text[
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\)]\)", FontSize -> 20], {xmin,
     0.06}]], 
 Epilog -> {Inset[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(min\)]\)", Black, 20], 
    Offset[{-25, 41}, Scaled[{0, 0}]]]}, ImagePadding -> 55, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

> [image: fff]

---

### **Edit 1: Addressing the comment: keeping $U_{min}$ albeit within the [`PlotRange`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)**

---

```
a = 2; U[x_] := -(a/x)^6 + (a/x)^12; min = 
 Solve[D[U[x], x] == 0, x]; xmin = min[[2, 1]][[2]]; potmin = 
 Solve[U[xmin] == Um, Um]; Umin = potmin[[1, 1]][[2]]; k = 
 D[U[x], {x, 2}] /. x -> xmin;

p1 = Plot[U[x], {x, 1.9, 3.8}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["r", FontSize -> 20, Black], 
     Style["U(r)", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{1.8, 4}, {1.5 Umin, 0.6}}, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Energia potencial"}, {Right, Top}], 
   Ticks -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {1.8, 0}];

p2 = Plot[Umin + k/2 (x - xmin)^2, {x, a, xmin + xmin - a}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Aproximação harmônica"}, {Right, Top}]]

p3 = Plot[Umin, {x, 1.8, xmin}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];

Show[p1, p2, p3, Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
 Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
 Graphics[Text[
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\)]\)", FontSize -> 20], {xmin,
     0.06}]], 
 Epilog -> {Text[
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(min\)]\)", 
     FontSize -> 20], {1.93, Umin - 0.07}]}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]}]
```

> [image: pp2]

---

### **Original answer**

---

```
a = 2; U[x_] := -(a/x)^6 + (a/x)^12; min = 
 Solve[D[U[x], x] == 0, x]; xmin = min[[2, 1]][[2]]; potmin = 
 Solve[U[xmin] == Um, Um]; Umin = potmin[[1, 1]][[2]]; k = 
 D[U[x], {x, 2}] /. x -> xmin;
Show[Plot[U[x], {x, 1.9, 3.8}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["r", FontSize -> 20, Black], 
    Style["U(r)", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{1.8, 4}, {1.5 Umin, 0.6}}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Energia potencial"}, {Right, Top}], 
  Ticks -> {None, None}, AxesOrigin -> {1.8, 0}], 
 Plot[Umin + k/2 (x - xmin)^2, {x, a, xmin + xmin - a}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Aproximação harmônica"}, {Right, Top}]], 
 Plot[Umin, {x, 1.8, xmin}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}], 
 Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
 Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}}]}], 
 Graphics[Text[
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(r\), \(0\)]\)", FontSize -> 20], {xmin,
     0.06}]], 
 Graphics[Text[
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(U\), \(min\)]\)", 
    FontSize -> 20], {1.651, Umin}]], 
 AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[{0.0, 0.05}]}]
```

> [image: plot1]

Comment: No, I want to keep the Umin on the image.

Comment: @AndreLuizMB can you have a look at the updated answer and let me know if Edit 2 is what you wanted?

Comment: Hello bmf! Thanks a lot! Edit 2 is exactly what a i ve searching for

Comment: @AndreLuizMB thanks for letting me know. Glad I was able to help. Just a quick comment: you can manipulate the exact position from `Offset` and if you want to place it further to the left for example, just change the value of `ImagePadding`. If this answer resolved the issue you were facing, please consider upvoting it and/or accepting it  using the arrows and checkmark next to it :-)

Answer (score 6):

Set the horizontal plot range as `{1.8,4}` as suggested in comments and use the option [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html) to avoid clipping of labels.

You can get the whole picture using a single `Plot` using `{U[x], ConditionalExpression[Umin + k/2 (x - xmin)^2, a <= x <= xmin + xmin - a]}` as the first argument and adding the dashed lines as `Epilog`:

```
Plot[{U[x], ConditionalExpression[Umin + k/2 (x - xmin)^2, a <= x <= xmin + xmin - a]},
 {x, 1.9, 3.8},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red},
 AxesLabel -> {Style["r", FontSize -> 20, Black], Style["U(r)", FontSize -> 20, Black]},
 AxesOrigin -> {1.8, 0},
 AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[Medium], Arrowheads[{-Medium, Medium}]},
 PlotRange -> {{1.8, 4}, {1.7 Umin, 0.6}},
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 20}, {5, 30}},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Energia potencial", "Aproximação harmônica"}, {Right,  Top}],
 Ticks -> {None, {{Umin, Style[Subscript[U, "min"], FontSize -> 20]}}},
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}, {1.8, Umin}}],
    Text[Style[Subscript[r, 0], GrayLevel[.4], FontSize -> 20], {xmin, 0}, {0, -1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: very nice and minimal!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were seeking? It seems that you did not want the axes to intersect.

```
Plot[{U[x], 
  ConditionalExpression[Umin + k/2 (x - xmin)^2, 
   a <= x <= xmin + xmin - a]}, {x, 1.9, 3.8}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Red}, Axes -> {False, True}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["r", FontSize -> 20, Black], 
   Style["U(r)", FontSize -> 20, Black]}, AxesOrigin -> {1.8, 0}, 
 AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads[Medium], Arrowheads[{-Medium, Medium}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{1.8, 4}, {1.7 Umin, 0.6}}, 
 ImagePadding -> {{50, 20}, {5, 30}}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"Energia potencial", "Aproximação harmônica"}, {Right, 
    Top}], Ticks -> {None, {{Umin, 
     Style[Subscript[U, "min"], FontSize -> 20]}}}, 
 Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{xmin, 0}, {xmin, Umin}, {1.8, Umin}}],
   Dashing[False], Arrow[{{1.9, 0}, {4, 0}}], 
   Text[Style[Subscript[r, 0], GrayLevel[.4], FontSize -> 20], {xmin, 
     0}, {0, -1}]}]
```

[image]